# onChange is not triggered when i upload a image in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to upload a image in the react js
I am sending property to a component like

```
<Input 
    changed={(event) => this.ChangedHandler(event)} 
    clicked={(event) => this.ClickedHandler(event)} 
 />
```

and i am receiving like from another functional component

```
const Input = (props) =>{
  return(
     <input
        onChange={props.changed} 
        onClick={props.clicked} 
    />
    <label>
        <input id="myFile" type="file"/>
        Upload File
    </label>
 )
}
```

when i was click while try to upload a image onClick event is triggered correctly, But choose the file for upload onChange should be triggered but that is not happen.

Comment: And what is the connection between input[type=file] and another with event handlers?

Comment: @dfsq i update my question accordingly.

Comment: And what is the connection between `input[type=file]` and input with event handlers? Plus your component's render is not valid.

Comment: input with event handler is a component, that sends the event handlers as props to the functional component "const Input".

Answer (score 0):

In your component `Input` you are not passing the props correctly. This is how you will do it.

```
<Input 
   changed={(event) => { this.ChangedHandler(event) }} 
   clicked={(event) => { this.ClickedHandler(event) }} 
/>
```

In your `Input` component file, you will do this.

```
const Input = (props) => {
  return(
    <input 
      type="file" 
      onChange={props.changed} 
      onClick={props.clicked} 
    >
      Upload
    </input>
   )
 }
```

Comment: if i want to upload a file type should be file.("type=file")

Comment: Sorry did that by mistake, @fabian_schultz editted my answer. Hope that helps.